# It seems my IntelliJ cannot find my csv file?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

So ive made a class to keep track of the data i've imported:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ImportData {
    public ImportData() {
    }
    public static ArrayList<Pizza> readData() throws IOException{
    String file = "Users/mathiaspoulsen/Desktop/SP3MarioPizza/pizzas.csv";
    ArrayList <Pizza> content = new ArrayList<>();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            String [] lineArr = line.split(",");
            Pizza pizza = new Pizza (Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]),lineArr[1],Double.parseDouble(lineArr[2]));
            content.add(pizza);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //Some error logging
    }
    return content;
}
```

I have then tried to run it in the main method to see if it loads the csv-file corectly. Like this:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /*    int i = 0;
        String fileName = "pizzas.csv";
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
        System.out.println(pathToFile.toAbsolutePath());
*/
       // ArrayList<Pizza> pizzas = ImportData.readData();
        System.out.println(ImportData.readData());
    }
}
```

The output of this program is: []

Why dont it display the pizzas? The pizzas in the csv-file a structured like this:

PizzaNumber(int),PizzaName(String), price(double)

1,MARGHERITA,69.00

Comment: I assume you want `"/Users/` as your file path

Comment: Also, is `//Some error logging`  literally in your code? You should actually fill that in

Comment: Once you do fix the filepath... `line = br.readLine()` only needs called once within the loop unless you want to skip every other line

Comment: Replace `//Some error logging` with `e.printStackTrace();` so that you can actually see what is going wrong. Also, as OneCricketeer mentioned, your file path does not look valid for what you want. To avoid issues specify the full path like this: `"C:/Users/mathiaspoulsen/Desktop/SP3MarioPizza/pizzas.csv"`

Comment: Thanks for the answers! 2 things went wrong. 1. String file = "Users/mathiaspoulsen/Desktop/SP3MarioPizza/pizzas.csv"; should be String file = "/Users/mathiaspoulsen/Desktop/SP3MarioPizza/pizzas.csv"; 2. String line = String line = br.readLine(); should be String line = ""; Also changed my FileNotFoundException e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the line multiple times which most likely was causing your issue just read the line once and check to make sure it is not null in the while statement before parsing it. Also, it would be better to check to make sure the parse is successful.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImportData {
  public ImportData() {
  }

  public static ArrayList<Pizza> readData() throws IOException {
    String file = "/Users/your/path/pizza.csv";
    ArrayList<Pizza> content = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineArr = line.split(",");
        content.add(new Pizza(Integer.parseInt(lineArr[0]), lineArr[1], Double.parseDouble(lineArr[2])));
      }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } 
    return content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! 2 things went wrong. 
1.   String file = "Users/mathiaspoulsen/Desktop/SP3MarioPizza/pizzas.csv"; should be
  String file = "/Users/mathiaspoulsen/Desktop/SP3MarioPizza/pizzas.csv";
2. String line = String line = br.readLine(); should be 
String line = "";

Also changed my FileNotFoundException e